# Can I use nodejs behind apache to handle OIDC authentication and pass the authenticated user back to apache?

Tags: node.js, apache, openid-connect, reverse-proxy

I have a legacy Apache HTTPD application into which I would like to replace basic authentication with OpenID connect (OIDC) authentication.

`mod_auth_openidc` is not an option due to the platform architecture and operating system.

I am exploring the idea of using nodejs and `passport-openidconnect` to handle the OIDC bit and somehow pass the authenticated user session on to apache. I intend to run nodejs along-side apache on the same host.

What could it look like? I imagine having httpd on port 443 proxy the OIDC process through to nodejs on some other port.

Is this possible?